# Legitimate papers refuting the significance of the golden ratio in art?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio, art

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask about this, but is there any legitimate peer-reviewed paper refuting the significance of the golden ratio in art? I can find numerous websites and blogs scattered around the web on this topic, but I don't feel they are solid enough. If there are better places to ask this, please kindly direct me to there.

Comment: Mario Livio's book, The Golden Ratio, cites some papers about this.

Comment: From a review of Livio: The seventh chapter, the longest in the book, contains a fascinating discussion of the golden ratio in arts and aesthetics. Livio offers a detailed and skeptical examination of claims that the golden ratio appears in artistic works ranging from the early Renaissance through the nineteenth century.... Finally, he offers a skeptic's look at the aesthetics of the golden ratio, examining psychological studies on geometric beauty, and concluding that the notion that the golden ratio provides a "universal canon of ideal beauty'' is false.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at Livio's book?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late reply, I've been unable to access the internet for a while. But, thanks for the answer, I'll be sure to check that book, it looks really fascinating